# What does "as many an empty stomach as a full one" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you explain what the expression means in the following excerpt?
Is it saying something about how many times the child will get meals?

https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/the-law-of-life-by-jack-london-part-one/4656578.html

> That child was always weeping, and it was sickly. It would die soon, perhaps, and they would burn a hole through the frozen ground and pile rocks above to keep the wolves away. And what difference would it make? A few years at best, and **as many an empty stomach as a full one**. And in the end, death waited, ever-hungry and hungriest of them all.

Comment: I think the interpretation about the child's feeding is correct - it's in the time frame of *a few years at best* - this is the life that awaits the child, whose life or death would make no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase could be understood to mean that as many people were fed as were famished, or that there were times when food was available and times when famine prevailed.

Comment: Thank you. I think the second interpretation seems to fit better into the context.

Comment: I think it means that the best the child could expect was a few more years of life during which it would be hungry as often as not.